# SQL Query is Incorrect (Wrong output)

Tags: sql

I am having a bit of trouble with this SQL problem

The Tables:

```
A:
ID            DistrictID 
1              3
2              3
3              4




B:
DistrictID                  Congressional_District
1                                                  8
2                                                2
3                                              14
4                                               7
5                                              11




C:
ID            Gender 
1              M
3              F
4               M
```

The problem:

I tried the following query.

Getting this result but it says it is incorrect output:

Maybe I am reading the problem wrong, and help would be appreciated.

Comment: "the following query" Do you mean the preceding query or do you mean to include and additional one?

Comment: What is wrong? What are you getting?

Comment: There are no test cases, but the compiler says it is the wrong output and I am not sure why or what part of the question I am not understanding

Comment: Probably ask the person or website that gave you the assignment. To me, it looks like the output of your query aligns with what is expected.

Comment: It says sorted by gender and district. You have the order wrong.

Comment: It is a hackerRank challenge on SQL Count. However, the website doesn't provide any test cases therefore I wanted to ask here before I moved forward.

Comment: SELECT
    B.Congressional_District,
    C.Gender,
    COUNT(*) AS Gender_Count
FROM
    A
JOIN B ON A.DistrictID = B.DistrictID
JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE
    C.Gender IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    C.Gender,
    B.Congressional_District
ORDER BY
    C.Gender,B.Congressional_District;



I fixed the order but still getting "Incorrect output"

Comment: The "WHERE C.Gender IS NOT NULL" is spurious. It can never be NULL, since you're doing a JOIN, and not a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem below specify that the order must be gender first. in your Query you need to invert the order by of the fields:

```
ORDER BY
  C.Gender;
  B.Congressional_District,
```

Comment: I have made the changes (Updated it on my post), yet still saying "incorrect output".

Comment: try to change the order of the select as well select gender first than congress

Comment: Thats fixed the issues thanks for the help

Comment: To be clear, this is yet another example of a ludicrous "exam question". Changing the order of the fields in the SELECT statement is 100% irrelevant, practically speaking.

Comment: It looks like the exercise is more about attention to details than the SQL script itself. Even if the order of the column is not important if this was a question on a job interview getting the column order right is the most important thing as it shows that you read and understood the requirements. If this was a real job request as well you would have wasted time arguing with your QA team which is building test cases based on the requirements not your code.